# Can I use <icon> element in HTML5? It fails the W3C validator

Tags: seo, html, html5, validation, w3c-validation

When I go to the W3C validator service, to try out if it complains about using an `<icon>` element, with this example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <icon></icon>
</body>
</html>
```

The error that I get back from it says the following:

> Error: Element icon not allowed as child of element body in this
>   context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
>
> From line 8, column 2; to line 8, column 7
>
> Content model for element body: Flow content.

The part where it says "not allowed as child of", suggested to me that the `<icon>` element as such may actually exist, but is intended for something else, and therefore doesn't fit there, structurally. But when i go to the [MDN HTML elements reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element), there is no `<icon>` element listed.

Using it works however (I can use it to display a Fontawesome icon), and seeing how HTML5 suggests that we are allowed to make up our own elements (and Angularjs advocates using arbitrary element names for directives), would it actually be bad to use it in practice?

Would it be bad for SEO? Would readers complain? Would parsers complain? Would it not be future-proof?

Comment: Related: [Are custom elements valid HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845011/are-custom-elements-valid-html5)

Comment: Browsers are required to do the best they can with invalid markup but you do not want browsers guessing at your intentions. Browsers will treat it as "tag soup". Google for that. It is not future proof either. There is no such thing as `<icon>` so don't use it except as a custom element as shown in the link by @MaximillianLaumeister but I don't know if that link is up-to-date or not.

Comment: Yup, @MaximillianLaumeister's link is the proper solution, as it describes how custom elements are supposed to be declared. More specifically, they need to include a dash in their name. Even in my example code for the W3C validator, if i just rename `<icon>` to `<my-icon>`, it validates.

Comment: Keep in mind that custom elements only work in Chrome and Firefox. His link also doesn't answer any of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Include a reference link in your `<head></head>` the same way you
   would link your CSS file:
   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">`
2. Reference your `<icon>` as `<i class="material-icons">cloud</i>`

You can learn more about it at [W3Schools Icon Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/default.asp) 
Appended
I concede to @unor in that, `<span>` is another way to reference an icon. There seems to be some serious [debates between `<i>` and `<span>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span), but both methods seem to function. I can understand that one person would say that W3C's use of `<span>` is correct. After all, they set all of the specifications. However... when large, global firms (aka Google) use `<i>`... well, let's just say that using `<i>` isn't going to end any time soon.

Sources supporting the `<i>` tag:
[W3.CSS Icons](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_icons.asp)  *mentions* that both `<i>` and `<span>` can be used (but, their examples use `<i>`.)
[Google: Material Icons Guide](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/)
Sources supporting the `<span>` tag:
[W3C Icon Font](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Icon_Font_with_an_On-Screen_Text_Alternative)
[CSS Tricks: HTML for Icon Font Usage](https://css-tricks.com/html-for-icon-font-usage/)
[Bootstrap's UseIconic Font Recommendation](https://useiconic.com/open/) indicates `<span>` for HTML and `<img>` for SVG, and 
[Font Awesome: Basic Use](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use) illustrates using both by wrapping the `<span><i></i></span>` tags (although this seems a little redundant to me).
I suppose our best option will be decisions based on the programming language and icon use.

Comment: The `i` element is [not the correct choice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501699/1591669) for this. Use `span` instead.

Comment: @unor edited answer